# Split file as argument by '/' (slash)

Tags: c

I have a bit of code and I need to split the words in the filename and store them separately.

Example:

Input -> filename ( e.g. `/Users/user/Documents/uni`)

Storage in variable/array as separate words ( not sure how):

`char array/struct array = Users user Documents uni`

How can I achieve the above example of storing words with C?

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 char filename[255];
 for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
 {
    strcpy(&filename[i], argv[i]);
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: An example of: 1. arguments provided to your program, 2. your desired resulting data in-code from those arguments (i.e. elaborate *exactly* what you mean by "store them separately"), is required for your question. Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71360920/edit) to include *all* relevant data. The picture in your head of what you want may be crystal clear to you, but we're not mind-readers.

Comment: I have updated my question @WhozCraig see if its clearer

Comment: It is indeed clearer. I think you'l find `strtok` to be helpful here. Worth a hit in your C reference. And melon is right, `argc` isn't what you seem to think it is. I think a review of your reference materials is warranted.

Comment: I have tried `strtok` but its basically only giving me the first word before the `/`, so `Users` and not all the words ( `Users user Documents uni` following that that are delimited by `/`. I needed some kind of loop that goes over every word of the filename and separates it by `/` but I am unsure on how to achieve that

Comment: Wait, is the *single* argument passed to your program a fore-slash file or directory path or not? What do you mean "and not all the words following that that are delimited by /" ? I suspect you just don't understand how `strtok` works (of which there are *hundreds* of examples on this site alone).

Comment: the argument passed is my directory path. It may well be that there are references but not specific to my case (at least that I could find). More importantly, if I knew how to do it I wouldn't be here asking which is the whole point of this site.

Comment: Still not clear what you really want, but  I still think you're not tokenizing correctly. [example here](https://godbolt.org/z/sPvvovWbG). What you *do* with those strings is up to you, but you can easily split a writable string using strtok so long as you know the delimiter.

Comment: Unnecessary copying of data is a common flaw of programs written in C.  In this case, you almost certainly do *not* want to actually store each component of the path as a null-terminated string.  Instead, store the length and location of the first character (wide-character?) of each path component and use that information whenever you want to reference the data later.  (eg, you won't use `printf` or any of the `str*` function, but you will use `fwrite`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char filename[BUFSIZ];              // pathname
    int i;
    int n = 0;                          // number of words
    char **ary = NULL;                  // array of strings
    char *tok;                          // pointer to each token

    if (argc != 2) {                    // verify aruguments
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s pathname\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    strncpy(filename, argv[1], BUFSIZ);
    for (tok = strtok(filename, "/"); tok != NULL; tok = strtok(NULL, "/")) {
        if (NULL == (ary = realloc(ary, (n + 1) * sizeof(*ary)))) {
                                        // enlarge array of strings
            perror("realloc");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (NULL == (ary[n] = malloc(strlen(tok) + 1))) {
                                        // allocate memory for the word
            perror("malloc");
            exit(1);
        }
        strncpy(ary[n], tok, strlen(tok) + 1);
                                        // copy the token to the array
        n++;
    }

    // see the results
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("[%d] %s\n", i, ary[i]);
    }

    // free the allocated memory
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(ary[i]);
    }
    free(ary);

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile the code to the executable `a.out`, the outout will look like:

```
$ ./a.out /Users/user/Documents/uni
[0] Users
[1] user
[2] Documents
[3] uni
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve the desired outcome with this piece of code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 char word[255];
 const char s[2] = "/";
 char *token;
   if( argc == 2 ) {
      printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
   }
   else if( argc > 2 ) {
      printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
   }
 strcpy(word, argv[0]);
 token = strtok(word, s);
    while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
}
```